# Slow update query despite index

Tags: mysql

I have a query updating a large table (4.1 million rows) and using an even larger origin table on which I do aggregation (63 million rows):

```
update 
    table1 t1,
    (select 
        user_id, 
        count(distinct date(started_at)) as count_s 
    from sand s 
    where started_at >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    group by user_id) t2 
set m.distinct_days_1week = t2.count_s
where m.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Both tables are indexed on user_id.
sand table is also indexed on started_at

On other update queries I usually run full destination table update in less than 5 mins, but I guess since the origin table is large, it takes much longer time.
The subquery if run alone, runs in less than 4s (didnt measure exactly though).

Explain shows that indexes are used and that the where clause filters a large part of the big sand table.

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ALL                                                      12786201   100.0   Using where
1   UPDATE  m               eq_ref  PRIMARY,user_id_IDX PRIMARY 8   t2.user_id             1    100.0   Using where
2   DERIVED s               index   user_id_IDX,started_at_IDX  user_id_IDX 9       63784993    20.05   Using where
```

What am I missing to optimize that query?

Comment: How many rows will be updated?  If it is 4.1M, then it _will be_ slow -- Update has nontrivial overhead even for the simplest of queries.

Answer (score 0):

For `sand`, replace your single column `INDEX(started_at)` and `INDEX(user_id)` with the following.  Both are "composite" and "covering".  (I don't know which order is better.)

```
INDEX(started_at, user_id)
INDEX(user_id, started_at)
```

`DATE(NOW())` --> `CURDATE()`  (a trivial simplification)

Are `t1` and `m` the same???  Assuming so, it needs some kind of index starting with `user_id`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.